# Before vs previously

Tags: grammar

What is the exact usage of  `"Before"` and "`Previously`".  For example:

1. I mentioned this example before.
2. I mentioned this example previously.

What is the difference in meaning between the previous two examples regarding"  before - previously"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me, but in this example I consider "previously" to have been longer ago than "before". "Before" sort of sounds as though the example was mentioned a few sentences ago, while "previously" seems to imply that the example was mentioned in a further timeframe, such as two days ago.

Comment: @DogLover. Good point! I was thinking of this. And actually this is what drove me to be confused!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two sentences, unless you're using "before" as a spatial reference (I'm assuming you're not, as I have only ever heard that construction used in poetry, and OED even lists such a use as "archaic").

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/before 
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/previously

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/previously

Comment: I mean, obviously the phrase "I appeared before him" appears often enough; before is often used as a spatial preposition. The construction I'm referring to is, for example "the knuckles are behind; the palm is before" (you don't hear "before" being used as a spatial adverb very often).

Answer (score 0):

Previously would typically mean a single instance.

'I did this previously' likely implies that I had done this once in the past.
'I did this before' is less descriptive.

That said, I have heard both use interchangeably.